# Java 8 pass function as parameter

Tags: function, java-8

I have a function like this

```
int getSum(List<Dish>> list, Function function) { //function is not used yet 
     ...
     int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Dish::getA1).sum();
     ... 
     return sum;
}
```

I want to pass a function to it so that I can do this in the function where function can be Dish::getA1, Dish::getA2 etc.

```
  int getSum(List<Dish>> list, Function function) { //function is used  
     ...
     int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(function).sum();
     ... 
     return sum;
}
```

My question is how to make this function? This does not work:

```
Function func = Dish::getA1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int getSum(List<Dish> list, ToIntFunction<Dish> function)
```

should works.

You have to understand that `Function` is a generic type. So here you want a `Function` from a `Dish` instance to `Integer` (so `Function<Dish, Integer>`), but since you use `mapToInt`, it expects a `ToIntFunction` (function `Dish -> int`).

Comment: How to make the function? I need to do `Function f1 = Dish::getA1`, and `f2 = Dish::getA2`, etc.

Comment: @Bruce `ToIntFunction<Dish> function = Dish::getA1;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that takes an integer as a parameter, and returns a string, the parameter in your function will look like this:

```
public void methodToCallFunctionFrom(Function<Integer, String> yourFunction) {
```

Then when you call the function in the method it would look like:

```
String s = yourFunction.apply(5);
```